# JQuery Countdown + Server Sync with AppEngine

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to use jquery countdown to sync with the server so the time is the same for all visitors. The files are being hosted on AppEngine using the static settings to host the HTML. PHP doesn't work on AppEngine.

Would it be possible to sync with the server time using Python under AppEngine's static settings? - how would I use datetime.now() in Jquery?

```
function countdown() {
    var eventTime = new Date('May 23, 2012 08:00:00');
    $('#time-left').countdown({ until: eventTime, layout: '<ul class="timer"><li class="days">{dn}</li> <li class="hours">{hnn}</li><li class="mins">{mnn}</li><li class="secs">{snn}</li></ul>',
                                serverSync: function() { return new Date('datetime.now()') }});
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its difficult to calculate time in client side because its vary in different time zones.... so get the server time in UTC and create a local time variable in UTC offset, then compare sec deff in local time

```
// return string must be in UTC time yyyy/MM/dd H:mm:ss format in Json result
$.get("timerequestmethod", function (data) {
                var dateArray = data.split(' ');
                var seconds = getSeconds(dateArray);

                // create countdown until 'seconds' declare in above statement
            });

getSeconds = (function (dateArray) {
        var dt = dateArray[0].split('/');
        var tm = dateArray[1].split(':');
        var times = new Date();
        times.setUTCFullYear(dt[0], (dt[1] > 0 ? dt[1] - 1 : dt[1]), dt[2]);
        times.setUTCHours(tm[0]);
        times.setUTCMinutes(tm[1]);
        times.setUTCSeconds(tm[2]);
        return (times - new Date()) / 1000;
    });
```